# LDAP Query to check if user exists in a group or subgroup

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, ldap-query

I'm authenticating users against an LDAP server and I need to see if the user belongs to a particular group. All users belonging to a subgroup under this group should also be allowed to login. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    private String[] returnedAtts = { "sn", "givenName", "mail", "objectSid", "memberOf" };
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    LdapContext ldatCtxt = null;
    try{
        ldatCtxt= getInitialContext(userName, password);
    }
    catch(AuthenticationException e){           
        throw new AppException(AppMessageHandler.getClientString("invalidCredentials"));
    }
    String searchFilter = userSearchQuery.replace("$USERID$", userName);

    NamingEnumeration<?> answer = ldatCtxt.search(searchBase, searchFilter,searchCtls);
    String userGroup=null;
    if(answer==null || !answer.hasMoreElements()){
        throw new AppLoginException(AppMessageHandler.getClientString("invalidCredentials"));
    }
    SearchResult searchresult = (SearchResult) answer.next();
    Attribute memberOf = (Attribute) searchresult.getAttributes().get("memberOf");
    if(memberOf==null){
        throw new AppLoginException(AppMessageHandler.getClientString("userNotInADGroup"));
    }
    userGroup = (String) memberOf.get();                    
    String[] groups=userGroup.split(",");
    boolean isMemberOfGroup = false;
    for(String groupName:groups)
    {
        if(groupName.equals("CN="+appUserGrp))
            isMemberOfGroup = true;
    }
    if(!isMemberOfGroup){
            throw new AppLoginException(AppMessageHandler.getClientString("userNotInADGroup"));
        }
```

This works fine when I'm checking for a specific group, but doesn't work when a user from a subgroup(which is a member of the parent group - appUserGrp. Is there a way to check if a user belongs to a specific group or any subgroup that is a member of that group?

Here's a sample of the group structure that I have:

Group1

- User1
- User2
- SubGroup1

  -User3

  -User4
- SubGroup2

  -User5

Group2

- User6
- User7

User1-5 should be able to login, but user6 and user7 should not be able to login.

Comment: What is the LDAP server software you're using? Some implementations offer operational attributes to check membership in nested group structures.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming as you show searching for "ObjectSid", you are using Microsoft Active Directory.
If so, You can to use the extensible matching filter using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN. Query the group with the scope=BASE and Something like:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=John Smith,DC=MyDomain,DC=NET)
```

Should work.

More [examples are available.](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups)

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this out!

Comment: The example link does not work.

Comment: Try:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups